# Django: Data Flow Diagrams

Tags: python, django, dataflow-diagram

Is there any resource where can I get Django's data flow diagrams, I didn't find them on official site?

For example of how request is dispatched, how uploaded files handled etc.

Sultan

Answer (score 10):

There is no off-the-shelf solution for this but there a few options depending on your needs:

1. Document with a reference image

You can describe the process by this in-depth overview image of the django web communication.
[image: image resource: http://hitesh.in/2009/django-flow]

2. In-depth module dependency generation

   You can try to generate the python module dependency graph of your project. One way to this is using this tool: http://www.tarind.com/depgraph.html. But I'm afraid this method needs to be combined to a network communication detection tool.
3. Django middleware hooks + logging

   You can install hooks inside the middleware class described here  http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/. If you print the flow to logs (inside the hooks), you can reuse the logs to manually make diagram of the flow. (if you use the dot language, you might give yourself a head start).

Answer (score 0):

That's the only pretty picture you are going to find on django's
official docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/

For everything else, well the data flow is pretty much governed by the
Http's Request-Response cycle. So there is not much point in diagrams I think, rather you need documentation that explains the various 'hooks' provided between
a Request and a Response.

Note: there's no diagrams in the documents past v1.9.

Comment: Unfortunately the link has become unreachable.

Comment: Dead link, no Lucky luck there!